# Daily Limit for Unauthenticated in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube, youtube-api

I've written a short script in the Google Spreadsheet script editor to pull subscriber counts from a YouTube channel:

```
   function YouTubeSubs(channel){

   results = YouTube.Channels.list("statistics", {"forUsername":channel});

   return(results.items[0]['statistics']['subscriberCount']);
   }
```

And it works fine in the script editor - when I log the output or debug, it gives me the correct subscriber count.

But when I put it into the spreadsheet for use, such as **=YouTubeSubs('channelName')**, it's giving me this error:

**Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.**

I've used the YouTube API before so I'm not sure why it's happening in this situation. Any ideas?

Comment: have you enable the advanced services? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services

Comment: Yeah - and it works in the Script Editor, ya know? But I think I'm discovering that Custom Functions can't use the YouTube API or something. I may need to find another way to do what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use that service in a custom function. The list of available services can be found at:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services

You can use UrlFetchService though. So you can make a REST call to the YouTube API for access.

Here is a version that works. Note I used channelId but you could just swap id for forUsername if you prefer that.

```
function YoutubeSubs(chanId){
   var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key=YOURAPIKEY&part=statistics&id="+chanId;
   var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,{method:"get", muteHttpExceptions:true});
  return JSON.parse(res.getContentText()).items[0]["statistics"]["subscriberCount"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Advanced Google Service for YouTube [document](http://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/youtube) does not describe the limitation well.

But if you read the following [document](http://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services) carefully, you cannot use the service in the custom functions. Yet, you can do that by calling it under the [menu](http://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus).